# Critique my regimen please

Tags: workout-routines, program-review

I have a 6 day workout, abt 40min each day starts

- 3 to 6km on bike, usually about 8min

Then one of:

1 - deadlift - 3 setd of 10 of body weight on Olympic bar

- squat - 3 sets of 10, ~80% body weight, ATG
- bench - 3 sets of 10, ~ 60% body weight

2 - alternating Lunges - 3 sets of 10 alternating each leg, dumbells each hand, 40% body wieght total

- squats with dumbells each hand, 40%  body weight total

3 - longer bike, stairs, arc trainer

Any suggestions for improvements. Prefer to drop bmi,

Currently 100kg, 1.8m

Comment: I’d shorten the warmup on the bike to a max of five minutes, possibly even shorter. A warmup should do just that: warm you up. Any more will reduce your ability to lift weights.

Comment: Lots of focus on legs, not much targetting back / arms / shoulders? Goal is to just lose fat?

Answer (score 1):

### Adaptation requires *progressive overload*, but you’ve programmed for *regressive underload*.

It is well established that progressive strength and hypertrophy adaptations require progressively increasing one or more resistance training variables (volume, load, proximity to failure, etc.). Not only is your program missing this key element, it is actually set up for *regression*, based on your stated goals.

You appear to be using body weight to determine your load selection on the resistance training movements, and stated that you want to lower your BMI. *This means that your resistance training is going to get progressively easier as you lose weight*. It just doesn’t make sense to use body weight to determine your load selection, ever.

Instead, you should implement a progression strategy that allows you to consistently provide a meaningful challenge as you get stronger, such as one of the strategies outlined in this article  by Dr. Michael Zourdos: [How to Choose the Right Load Progression Strategy](https://www.strongerbyscience.com/weekly-load-progression/)